# Why is it not practical for the USN T-45 to be fitted with oxygen systems used in other trainers?

Tags: military, flight-training, oxygen, trainer

Back in April, the US Navy (USN) [grounded](http://www.foxnews.com/politics/2017/04/04/navy-instructor-pilots-refusing-to-fly-over-safety-concerns-pences-son-affected.html) all of its [T-45](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/McDonnell_Douglas_T-45_Goshawk) training flights due to issues with the cockpit oxygen system.  I personally heard about this before the grounding secondhand from someone in the program, who was familiar with an instructor who did not remember landing during a training flight.

A number of questions arise, but in order to keep with the single question style that seems to be preferred on this board, I will limit myself to one:

*Why is it not practical for USN T-45 trainers to be fitted with oxygen systems used in other trainers?*

The [T-6 Texan II](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Beechcraft_T-6_Texan_II), used in the USN [Primary Pilot training phase](https://www.reddit.com/r/aviation/comments/5j89tn/us_navy_and_marine_corps_flight_school_training/) uses an [onboard oxygen-generating system (OBOGS)](http://www.airforce-technology.com/projects/t6a-texan-ii-jpats/). I would assume that the US Air Force jet trainer uses one as well.  It surprises me that with a problem that has spanned several years and with a program that has been grounded for three months (and counting) and no solution on the horizon, such alternatives are not being considered.

Comment: My guess (with over 2k hours in mil jets) is cost. Despite being what is easily argued "safety of flight", this is not merely "buy one O2 system for each jet"; on top of the safe-for-flight testing, it would likely require structural changes due to where pipes/hoses/cables are placed. The T-45 specifically has *very little room* for any type of growth.

Comment: (For the record, I'm not saying that's a good reason.)

Comment: Fitting an entirely different oxygen system is like using a sledgehammer to crack a nut. They need to find out what's wrong with the existing system and roll out a fix. It could be something as simple as a seal, it just takes time to resolve these kinds of issues.

Comment: Remember as well that the Goshawk is a modified Bae Hawk, a British design from the 1980s rather than an American design. I'd not be surprised if the entire electrical as well as mechanical hookup is different from that used by US manufacturers

Comment: @Pondlife, I guess I'll really know I've made it when you don't find a valid reason to edit one of my posts ;-)

Comment: Given that this system is mature, and that  the T-45 has been used in Navy Jet Training since about 1989, and that OBOGS systems are in use in multiple TMS in Naval Aviation, your question misses the point.  The question is, with a mature system that has worked for over two decades, *what has changed?*  That is what requires investigation and some internal honesty.  (While I have some suspicions, they will remain private until I know more). As with most systems and maintenance issues, fix the problem, which means find the root cause.  (As a reference, see UH-60 Spindles two decades ago).

Comment: For another reference point, see the stall fences on the top of an F-18's wing.

Comment: @KorvinStarmast agreed, thus my mention of having _a number of questions_.  I'm certainly interested as well in why this started now on a mature platform.

Comment: I guess my other concern is - how do you not it's *not* practical to put in a new system used in other trainers? (I certainly don't)  The question presumes that it isn't practical; nobody can answer that until what the root cause of OBOGS current failings is known, and then find out what it costs to remedy that versus ... doing something else.  Cut and past of an oxygen system from one TMS to another is hardly the way systems integration works anymore.

Comment: @KorvinStarmast fair enough.  I guess what I'm really asking is "Why aren't they doing that?".  I'm giving the USN (or the private contractor responsible) the benefit of the doubt for having considered and ruled out this approach.  If the consensus is that I've assumed too much, I'm happy to change my question.

Comment: A new OBOGS wouldn't necessarily help. The Hornets, Growlers, F-15s, SR-71s, U-2s, F-22s, and (recently) the F-35As (of various batches, but not B and C models) at Luke (but not elsewhere(?) strangely) and Super Hornets all have had previous hypoxia-like events, despite using some very different O2 systems over decades. In a recent T-45 event, even pure O2 did not help. Hypoxia root causes can be tricky to track down, some not related to OBOGS.

Comment: I think that since this is a current thing that even those in it have not successfully answered to their own satisfaction, I suspect that this question, as of this date time group, may be unanswerable ... until some time in the (hopefully near) future. But It's A Good Question in the sense of "what's the fix?"  or "why this fix?"

Comment: :-) I'm glad to hear you're happy with the reasons!